# Work done in moving a charge in circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current, potential, work

Why is the work done in moving a charge from one point to another in a circuit through any path the same even though heat and other losses are there?

Comment: W=VQ. For a constant V and constant charge, work done is constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all work is the same. Only work of the electrostatic force that defines the potential difference is the same.

For example, when unit charge makes one full cycle from minus terminal to the same minus terminal of a battery, work of this electrostatic force is always zero, no matter the details of the circuit (resistance, components...), because charge returned to a place of the same potential. But work of the friction force pre cycle (due to ohmic resistance) is not zero, but is given by $-RI$ where $R$ is ohmic resistance of the whole circuit and $I$ is current in the circuit. This work depends on the details of the circuit.